# How can I find out wether the current object is object<T> or object<T,U> in C#

Tags: c#, generics, typeof

I would like to know if there is a way in C# to find out if an object is `object<>` or `object<T,U>`.

In my program I deal with `ConsoleCommand`s.
These classes inherit from the `ConsoleCommandBase` class.
The `ConsoleCommand` class is either a `ConsoleCommand`, `ConsoleCommand<>` or `ConsoleCommand<T,U>`.

My goal is to determine at runtime which specific `ConsoleCommand` I'm currently looking at. I don't want to write a lot of if-else statements to determine the current object type like I did in my code. Therefore I can add a third `ConsoleCommand<T,U,V>` without touching this code.

Here is my current code. It works, but I have to tell whether it is `typeof(ConsoleCommand<>)` or `typeof(ConsoleCommand<T,U>)`.

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < commandList.Count; i++)
{
    if (properties[0].Equals(commandList[i].Id))
    {
        if (commandList[i] is ConsoleCommand)
        {
            (commandList[i] as ConsoleCommand).Invoke();
            validCommand = true;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            validCommand = false;
            var command = commandList[i];
            Type[] types = command.GetMyTypes();
            if(properties.Length - 1 >= types.Length)
            {
                var typeOfCommand = typeof(ConsoleCommand<,>);
                var genericType = typeOfCommand.MakeGenericType(types);
                object[] parameters = new object[types.Length];
                for(int j=0; j<types.Length; j++)
                {
                    parameters[j] = ConvertType(properties[j + 1], types[j]);
                }
                
                genericType.GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(command, parameters);
                validCommand = true;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it enough to know how many generic arguments are there?

Comment: It is never ConsoleCommand<>, you can't create objects of an open generic type.  Use Type.GetGenericArguments() if still necessary to count the number of type arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You in fact already have the code that you need, it just needs to be generisized.

For *example* (and I've refactored your code a bit, both to improve and to make it work for the example)

```
    class Foo<X,Z> {
        public string Invoke(X x, Z z) => $"{x} {z}";
    }
    class Bar<A,B,C> {
        public string Invoke(A a, B b, C c) => $"{a} {b} {c}";
    }

    //then to test

    var foo = new Foo<string, int>();
    callCommand(foo, new string[] { "id", "a", "1" });

    var bar = new Bar<string, int, double>();
    callCommand(bar, new string[] { "id", "a", "2", "3.1"});


    void callCommand(object command, string[] properties){
        var typeOfCommand = command.GetType();
        var types = typeOfCommand.GetGenericArguments();
        //var genericType = typeOfCommand.MakeGenericType(types);
        object[] parameters = new object[types.Length];
        for(int j=0; j<types.Length; j++)
        {
            parameters[j] = Convert.ChangeType(properties[j + 1], types[j]);
        }
        
        var x = typeOfCommand.GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(command, parameters);
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
```

Having said this, there are better alternatives to parsing the command line especially in .net core. Such as *System.CommandLine* and *DragonFruit*

Comment: Hi, this basically works now the way I wanted but with one difference: typeOfCommand.GetGenericArguments() always returns an empty array even tho my command is of type ConsoleCommand<T,U>. I changed this line to command.GetMyTypes() where I basically return a Type[] with the types T, U.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

Following are some helper method.

```
static bool IsInstanceOf(Type typeToCheck, object instance)
        {
            if(typeToCheck.IsGenericType)
            {
                return IsInstanceOfGenericType(typeToCheck, instance);
            }
            else
            {
                return instance.GetType() == typeToCheck;
            }
        }

        static bool IsInstanceOfGenericType(Type genericType, object instance)
        {
            Type type = instance.GetType();
            while (type != null)
            {
                if (type.IsGenericType &&
                    type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == genericType)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                type = type.BaseType;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Usage.

```
        ConsoleCommandBase v1 = new ConsoleCommand();
        ConsoleCommandBase v2 = new ConsoleCommand<int>();
        ConsoleCommandBase v3 = new ConsoleCommand<int, int>();

        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand), v1));
        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand), v2));
        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand),v3));

        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand<>), v1));
        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand<>), v2));
        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand<>), v3));

        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand<,>), v1));
        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand<,>), v2));
        Console.WriteLine(IsInstanceOf(typeof(ConsoleCommand<,>), v3));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help :) Your code will work but I still have the issue that I would need to write if-else statements to determin what actual object it is. And this is what I don't wanted to do